# Error while enabling IIS optional feature IIS-ASPNET and IIS-NetFxExtensibility

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am unable to enable the optional feature IIS-ASPNET and IIS-NetFxExtensibility. When I am running following commands on powershell to enable features

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "IIS-NetFxExtensibility" -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "IIS-ASPNET" -All
```

I am getting below errors

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : The source files could not be downloaded.
Use the "source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more
information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "IIS-ASPNET" -All
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand
```

Comment: What's the windows version you using? Win10&11? Windows Server 20xx? When you ran this command, did the machine connect to network?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012 R2 standard build 9600 in this VM and I am not able to connect with network from this machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the machine connect to network, otherwise it cannot install successfully. Or download the new Volume Licensing media.

[You can't install features in Windows Server 2012 R2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/deployment/you-cant-install-features)

> Method 1: Connect to the Internet
> ­If the server can connect to Windows Update for the feature installation, let the server make the connection.

> Method 2: Use Windows Server 2012 R2 installation media
> If the server can't connect to Windows Update, download the new Volume Licensing media (released on December 11, 2013) and use the Install-WindowsFeature PowerShell command.